# youtube-dl -o cannot insert single backslash in config file (windows)

Tags: windows, regex, youtube

I have created a file in the

> %APPDATA%\youtube-dl\config.txt

as suggested at from the youtube-dl [doc](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/documentation.html#d6)

I need to place the output of the file to **D:\Personal\music**

but the problem is that I cannot seem to get a single Backslash

this code

```
-c -v -o D:\\personal\\music
```

gives the below output

> [debug] User config: ['-c', '-v', '-o', 'D:\\personal\\music']

if I change it as below

```
-c -v -o D:\personal\music
```

gives the below output

> [debug] User config: ['-c', '-v', '-o', 'D:personalmusic']

Please help on the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the back-slashes are causing the effects you report, but they are easily avoided by using forward-slashes: Windows file-systems don't care which you use.

However, as I read the `youtube-dl` documentation, you need to include a file mask as well as the directory in the output specification, so the entry should be:

```
-c -v -o D:/personal/music/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s
```

This assumes you want to use the default mask.